# Getting error uninitialized constant when attempting to save form to database (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error "uninitialized constant Admins::ProductsController::Product", I have been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong all day and not getting anywhere.

I am trying to submit data to a database through a form. I also have the controller and models in a subdirectory "admins".

**controllers/admins/products_controller.rb**

```
class Admins::ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  end

  private def product_parms
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

**views/admins/products/new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'layouts/adminsidebar' %>

<%= form_for :product, url: admins_products_path do |f| %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :content%>
<%= f.text_area :content%>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  namespace :admins do
    get 'new' => 'products#new'
    resources :products
  end

  devise_for :users

  root 'pages#index'

  get 'about' => 'pages#about'

  get 'productsdis' => 'products#productsdis'

  get 'adminpanel' => 'admins#adminpanel'

  get 'admin' => 'admins#admin'

end
```

**Migration file**

```
  def change
    create_table :admin_products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**models/admin/product.rb**

```
class Admin::Product < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have a really do have a `Product` class in `models/product.rb`? You may want to actually explicity nest the module with `module Admins; class ProductsController;` see https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: In the `product_params` method in your `ProductsController`, you’re missing a `:` in front of `product`.

Comment: Added my product.rb to the post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing :  still giving same error though.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling `Product.new` in your `Admin::ProductsController` where it should be `Admin::Product.new`